# Can not enter sda_3 crpypt password when booting up!

Tags: boot, login, password, encryption

I have just built my first computer and installed `Ubuntu 16.04`.

When ever I boot up it appears with a purple screen and Ubuntu logo, under is a black box asking for my `sda_3 crypt` password.

When I enter the password nothing happens, the only way to get to the login page is to cntl alt del then boot up in recovery mode.

On the black screen there with white letters think its the code screen it again asks for my password for `sda_3 crypt`.

I know my password might not appear same as the code screen so why wont it work on the main screen.

How can I either enter my password successfully or get rid of it completely?

Comment: I meant sda_3 in the title

Answer (score 0):

It seems like defined your HDD to have `full disk encryption`

e.g. according to [the document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto) you can enable `full disk encryption` during install phase:

> During installation, check the checkbox “Encrypt the new Ubuntu
>   installation for security”.

Since you just installed the computer, and you want to get rid from it completely:

- The simple solution will be to reinstall Ubuntu on the same machine
- This time without Encrypting the disk.

  - i.e. this time - do NOT check the checkbox “Encrypt the new Ubuntu
    installation for security”

Comment: ok nice one cheers for the info:

Comment: @Vauban - If my answer was useful for you please [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer/)